# Can we scroll iPhone Photo Library to Bottom Programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, uiimagepickercontroller, photo-gallery

In my app I need to select the image from the Photo Library and I have hundreds of photos in that. The issue is latest photos captured by Camera, saves at the bottom of the Photo Library and thus, I have to scroll all over down to select the latest pictures, captured by me. Is there any way by which I can scroll the ImagePickerViewController's view to bottom or can I store the latest pictures at the top?

Answer (score 4):

```
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^()
        {
               UIView *imagePickerView = imagePickerController.view;
               UIView *view = [imagePickerView hitTest:CGPointMake(5,5) withEvent:nil];
               while (![view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] && view != nil)
               {
                    view = [view superview];
               }
               if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
               {
                   UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *) view;
                   CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
                   CGFloat y = MAX(contentOffset.y, [scrollView contentSize].height-scrollView.frame.size.height);
                   CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, y);
                   [scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
               }
       }];
```